# R - How do I calculate a mean value at intervals for categorical variables in time sequence data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```
Stamp   Time    Box Internal    External
1   19:00   B1  35.119  8.978
2   19:00   B2  23.131  11.139
3   19:00   B3  33.133  11.431
4   20:00   B1  27.09   8.481
5   20:00   B2  6.073   8.879
6   20:00   B3  29.154  9.571
7   21:00   B1  34.15   8.68
8   21:00   B2  33.698  11.041
9   21:00   B3  24.178  8.481
```

I am using ggplot2 to plot the geom_line of time sequence data for each box, but what I want to do is plot the mean value of $External for each time interval.  Each box has internal and external sensors, but if I plot the data like this:

```
my.plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = Stamp, y = Temp, color = Box), myData) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Stamp, y = External), myData) +
  theme_bw()
```

...there are three times as many data points for the "External" line.  I would like to plot the mean of External for each Time interval as an additional line on the same chart.  I'm using Stamp as my x variable because there are several days worth of data so the time wraps.  Any advice?

An alternative could be to include the mean External in additional rows like this:

```
Stamp   Time    Box Internal
1   19:00   B1  35.119
2   19:00   B2  23.131
3   19:00   B3  33.133
4   19:00   MX  14.521
```

Comment: Your code ( `y = Temp`) does not run, did you mean `y = Time` instead?

Comment: `stat='summary', fun.y='mean'` should do it. This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Group by `Box` and apply stat_summary mean:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(Time,External,group=Box), data=myData) + stat_summary(fun.y='mean')
```

Your x-axis should not be Stamp, it has no meaning.